# Why doesnt element update after call to axios in a Sails.js app?

Tags: sails.js, axios

Not sure if this a Sails.js issue or me missing something implementing `axios`. I am trying to follow this basic example from `axios` docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html).

I am referencing the axios library via the CDN URL.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})

<div id="app">{{ info }}</div>
```

All I see inside the `<div id="app">` is `[]`. The call to the API is successful as evidenced by `console.log(response)` but the div does not update.

Tried changing `mounted` to `created` with no luck.

Am I missing additional setup/configuration?

Comment: Interestingly, this works as expected outside Sails.js (using pure HTML and JS)

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, discovered that `Sails.js` uses something called [`parasails`](https://github.com/mikermcneil/parasails) which does auto-magic hookup for `vue.js`. Essentially, I moved my code to the `parasails` created `javascript` file and everything works as expected.

Looks like `vue` app created in my js file was overridden by the objects created in the js file created via `parasails`